# Atlassian Confluence REST API Error: Current user not permitted to use Confluence

Tags: python, python-3.x, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm trying to update a page on Confluence using a Python script but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Abdullah.Khawer/Desktop/find-secrets-in-code-to-alert-on-slack-and-track-on-confluence/main.py", line 76, in <module>
    page_id = conf.get_page_id(page_space, page_title)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/atlassian/confluence.py", line 220, in get_page_id
    return (self.get_page_by_title(space, title, type=type) or {}).get("id")
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/atlassian/confluence.py", line 305, in get_page_by_title
    response = self.get(url, params=params)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/atlassian/rest_client.py", line 288, in get
    response = self.request(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/atlassian/rest_client.py", line 260, in request
    self.raise_for_status(response)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/atlassian/confluence.py", line 3245, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(error_msg, response=response)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: Current user not permitted to use Confluence
```

My Python script looks as follows:

```
from atlassian import Confluence

conf_site = os.getenv("CONFLUENCE_SITE")
conf_user = os.getenv("CONFLUENCE_USER_EMAIL_ID")
conf_pass = os.getenv("CONFLUENCE_USER_TOKEN")

conf = Confluence(url=conf_site, username=conf_user, password=conf_pass)
```

Python script reference: [GitHub > abdullahkhawer > find-secrets-in-code-to-alert-on-slack-and-track-on-confluence > main.py](https://github.com/abdullahkhawer/find-secrets-in-code-to-alert-on-slack-and-track-on-confluence/blob/v1.0.0/main.py)

How to fix this? The username and password for the user I used are correct. The user is a service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work, I had to do all of the following on the Atlassian user (which is a service account in my case):

- Give access to the Confluence app.
- Give the `View` and `Add` permissions in the desired space.
- Give the `Can edit` permission on the page in that space.
- Create an API token and use it instead of password.

Comment: Well obviously you need permissions... Anyway sometimes you can encounter Confluence error out of blue. This is just Confluence stuff and it will make you angry sometimes. Give it few days and it usually goes back to normal.